# ActionScript 3 - referencing whith Static Methods

Tags: actionscript-3, methods, static, reference

Is there a way to make an static method act over an object of its class that is already on the stage, without using the keyword "this"? I mean, like "generic object of this class: do what I'm telling you to do, wathever your instance name"

My goal is to create an method that get called by any object of this class, based on the changing on the value of an external variable, but since I cannot use the "this" keyword to reffer to each instance, I could not figure out a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? It's anything but clear from your description what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but maybe using a singleton pattern would solve your problem??

Comment: It appears to be an issue with not understanding scope and object reference in actionscript 3 versus actionscript 2. I can tell you right now, creating static variables or methods to act as references to classes is a really, really bad idea. It's directly contrary to the very foundation of good coding practices including OOP. But, as mentioned above, perhaps expanding on your question is in order.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you have access that object some other way (something like this):

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip
    import flash.events.Event
    public class Something extends MovieClip
    {
        private static var group:Vector.<Something> = new Vector.<Something>();

        public function Something()
        {
            // doing this on added and removed is generally more reliable.
            // BUT! it does not give you accesses to all instances, only the
            // ones which currently have a parent
            addEventListener( Event.ADDED, addedHandler ); 
            // that said, since AS3 has no destructor, removed is the only 
            // way to clean up instances
            addEventListener( Event.REMOVED, removeHandler );
        }

        public static function doSomethingWithClass():void
        {
            for( var i:int = 0; i < group.length; i++ )
            {
                trace( group[ i ] );
            }
        }

        private function addedHandler( event:Event ):void
        {
            group.push( this );
        }

        private function removeHandler( event:Event ):void
        {
            group.splice( group.indexOf( this ), 1 );
        }
    }
}
```